# Did I miss a consecutive day?

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I was up to about 68 consecutive days on my `Fanatic` badge. I was super excited to be so close to getting it. I had worked quite hard to ensure that I wouldn't miss a day: I set up reminders, I came to the site more than once per day, I calculated the start and end of a UTC day in my AEST timezone and I frequently checked that the number was indeed increasing when I went to the site. Don't worry though, the badge was doing its job; nearly every time I went to the site to count a visit, I also ended up doing a heap of other things that I wouldn't have done otherwise (answering questions, doing reviews, editing posts, etc.).

And then yesterday (Sunday) I went to the site and found that the number had reset to 1. NOOOOO :'( That made me very sad. I accept that nothing can be done about this, however I'd like to know why it happened. I'm fairly confident I opened the site on Saturday.

So my question is this: Did I actually miss a day or is there some other factor I'm not aware of?

Comment: Looks like you only hit the homepage and chat; neither of those count. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485

Comment: @Shog9 What. Awww :'( So I didn't even miss a day and I still lose my progress? That's very disappointing. Can we maybe have a better description on the badge? I mean I realise the goal is that if you're a true fanatic you'll be on the site enough to get the badge anyway, but I love this site and worked hard for that badge. I can't help but feel cheated.

Comment: @Clonkex gold badges are hard to get however, so don't be so disappointed. In my first attempt at that badge I missed a Sunday also, on day #90 or so ... :/ I also discovered that accessing with the SE app seems to also not count as access, or at least that was what I noticed via some experiments. Guess it's back to square one again...

Comment: *I was super excited to be so close to getting it* I have seen users report here about losing it at 99 days ...

Comment: @rene So have I since making this post, that's gotta be a bit soulcrushing if you were excited for it. Well anyway I realised I might get the Unsung Hero badge in a week or so if I'm lucky, so I might get my first gold badge that way :P

Comment: @Shog9 Boom, finally got it! :D